# Algorithm for finding the smallest number of precise squares which amount is n

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic, time-complexity

I am supposed to write a function with one argument `n` and the function should count the smallest number of precise squares which amount is `n`. For example if n=10, the function should return 2 (10=3<sup>2</sup> +1<sup>2</sup>). So far i have implemented some solution- using dynamic programming but I am not absolutely sure of its correctness:

```
Squares(n)
  dyn[0...n]
  dyn[0] <- 0 

  for k <- 1 to n
       dyn[k] <- k+1
       i <- 1
       j <- 1

       while j<=k do
          if dyn[k-j] < dyn[k]
               dyn[k] <- dyn[k-j]
          i <- i+1
          j <- i*i

      dyn[k] <- dyn[k]+1
   k <- n

   return dyn[n]
```

Please, analyze my solution and if you can provide faster one? So far its running time is O(n<sup>3/2</sup>).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need any of this. You have to know some math stuff.

1. Some numbers are already squares `int(sqrt(x))**2 == x`
2. Some numbers can be represented as [sum of 2 squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) (Fermat)
3. Some numbers can be represented as [sum of 3 squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem#Relationship_to_the_four-square_theorem) (Legendre)
4. Every number can be represented as [sum of 4 squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) (Lagrange)

   So just check first two conditions and if non of them holds - return 4.

Comment: 0. Some numbers are squares.

Comment: @Henrik that was a sad mistake :-)